# How to add Test Users to Facebook Credits Testers?

Tags: facebook, testing, credits

I created [a Facebook test user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) for my application, and I want to test Facebook Credits API using this user. But when I click the link to make an order, popup comes up saying "Buy Facebook Credits", even though I added the user to credits testers.
Is there any way to test Facebook Credits API using test users ?

(I know that I can test Facebook Credits API using my real account without spending any credits, by adding my account to credits testers.)

Answer (score 0):

use this page: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/credits
u must enter your user id to credits testers field..

Comment: thank you for your reply! I know that I can use credits tester using MY userid. But what I want to know is, are there any way to use credits tester by using TEST USER ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Go to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/permissions` and in the **Test Users** section, hit the `modify` button. You'll get the list of IDs for all your test users.

Then the same process applies where you need to add those IDs to the Credits Testers `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/credits` section and provide valid credit card information.